# Laravel Livewire multispep form save data

Tags: php, laravel

this is my blade file
i have 2 problem i want different variable from javascript in this 3 step and in final page i want make a summary of 3 different preset and save to my database like:

```
id_client: = 1 ; order_1d =1 sub_order = 1

id_client: = 1 ; order_1d =1 sub_order = 2

id_client: = 1 ; order_1d =1 sub_order = 3
```

I want save in my database the information corretct
I might have 2 options:

1. I save every time I go to the next page
2. I save at the end but I don't know how to differentiate the variables that come from the javascript function

```
<pre>
<form wire:submit.prevent="submit" class="pt-3">

    <div>


{{--    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('ordini.id_tipo') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
        <label class="form-label" for="id_tipo">{{ trans('cruds.ordini.fields.id_tipo') }}</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="id_tipo" id="id_tipo" wire:model.defer="ordini.id_tipo" step="1">
        <div class="validation-message">
            {{ $errors->first('ordini.id_tipo') }}
        </div>
        <div class="help-block">
            {{ trans('cruds.ordini.fields.id_tipo_helper') }}
        </div>
    </div>--}}

    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-indigo mr-2" type="submit">
            {{ trans('global.save') }}
        </button>
        <a href="{{ route('admin.ordinis.index') }}" class="btn btn-secondary">
            {{ trans('global.cancel') }}
        </a>
    </div>

{{--</form>--}}






{{--Inizio sessione  vecchia, scelta cliente--}}




</form>







    <form>

        {{-- STEP 1 --}}

        @if ($currentStep == 1)


            <div class="step-one">
                <div class="card">

                    <div class="card-header text-xl text-pink-400">Farmaci della mattina</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('ordini.cliente_id') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="cliente">{{ trans('cruds.ordini.fields.cliente') }}</label>
                                    <x-select-list class="form-control" id="cliente" name="cliente" :options="$this->listsForFields['cliente']" wire:model="ordini.cliente_id" />
                                    <div class="validation-message">
                                        {{ $errors->first('ordini.cliente_id') }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="help-block">
                                        {{ trans('cruds.ordini.fields.cliente_helper') }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('prodotti') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="prodotti">{{ trans('cruds.ordini.fields.prodotti') }}</label>
                                    <x-select-list class="form-control" id="prodotti" name="prodotti" wire:model="prodotti" :options="$this->listsForFields['prodotti']" multiple />
                                    <div class="validation-message">
                                        {{ $errors->first('prodotti') }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="help-block">
                                        {{ trans('cruds.ordini.fields.prodotti_helper') }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Description</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" cols="2" rows="2" wire:model="description"></textarea>
                            <span class="text-danger">@error('description'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif

        {{-- STEP 2 --}}

        @if ($currentStep == 2)


            <div class="step-two">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-xl text-pink-400">Farmaci della pranzo</div>
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('ordini.cliente_id') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="cliente">{{ trans('cruds.ordini.fields.cliente') }}</label>
                                    <x-select-list class="form-control" id="cliente" name="cliente" :options="$this->listsForFields['cliente']" wire:model="ordini.cliente_id" />
                                    <div class="validation-message">
                                        {{ $errors->first('ordini.cliente_id') }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="help-block">
                                        {{ trans('cruds.ordini.fields.cliente_helper') }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('prodotti') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="prodotti">{{ trans('cruds.ordini.fields.prodotti') }}</label>
                                    <x-select-list class="form-control" id="prodotti" name="prodotti" wire:model="prodotti" :options="$this->listsForFields['prodotti']" multiple />
                                    <div class="validation-message">
                                        {{ $errors->first('prodotti') }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="help-block">
                                        {{ trans('cruds.ordini.fields.prodotti_helper') }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        @endif
        {{-- STEP 3 --}}

        @if ($currentStep == 3)


            <div class="step-three">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-xl text-pink-400">Farmaci della sera</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('ordini.cliente_id') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="cliente">{{ trans('cruds.ordini.fields.cliente') }}</label>
                                    <x-select-list class="form-control" id="cliente" name="cliente" :options="$this->listsForFields['cliente']" wire:model="ordini.cliente_id" />
                                    <div class="validation-message">
                                        {{ $errors->first('ordini.cliente_id') }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="help-block">
                                        {{ trans('cruds.ordini.fields.cliente_helper') }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('prodotti') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="prodotti">{{ trans('cruds.ordini.fields.prodotti') }}</label>
                                    <x-select-list class="form-control" id="prodotti" name="prodotti" wire:model="prodotti" :options="$this->listsForFields['prodotti']" multiple />
                                    <div class="validation-message">
                                        {{ $errors->first('prodotti') }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="help-block">
                                        {{ trans('cruds.ordini.fields.prodotti_helper') }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif

        {{-- STEP 4 --}}
        @if ($currentStep == 4)


            <div class="step-four">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header bg-secondary text-white">STEP 4/4 - Attachments</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque delectus officia inventore id facere at aspernatur ad corrupti asperiores placeat, fugiat tempora soluta optio recusandae eligendi impedit ipsam ullam amet!
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cv">CV</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" wire:model="cv">
                            <span class="text-danger">@error('cv'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="terms" class="d-block">
                                <input type="checkbox"  id="terms" wire:model="terms"> You must agree with our <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>
                            </label>
                            <span class="text-danger">@error('terms'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        @endif

        <div class="action-buttons d-flex justify-content-between bg-white pt-2 pb-2">

            @if ($currentStep == 1)
                <div></div>
            @endif

            @if ($currentStep == 2 || $currentStep == 3 || $currentStep == 4)
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-secondary" wire:click="decreaseStep()">Back</button>
            @endif

            @if ($currentStep == 1 || $currentStep == 2 || $currentStep == 3)
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-success" wire:click="increaseStep()">Next</button>
            @endif

            @if ($currentStep == 4)
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-primary">Submit</button>
            @endif


        </div>

    </form>


</div>

</pre>
```

my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Ordini;

use App\Models\Customer;
use App\Models\Ordini;
use App\Models\Product;
use Livewire\Component;

class Create extends Component
{
    public Ordini $ordini;

    public array $prodotti = [];

    public array $listsForFields = [];


    public $totalSteps = 4;
    public $currentStep = 1;







    public function mount(Ordini $ordini)
    {
        $this->ordini = $ordini;
        $this->initListsForFields();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.ordini.create');
    }

    public function submit()
    {
        $this->validate();

        $this->ordini->save();
        $this->ordini->prodotti()->sync($this->prodotti);

        return redirect()->route('admin.ordinis.index');


    }


    public function increaseStep(){
        $this->resetErrorBag();
        $this->validate();
        $this->currentStep++;
        if($this->currentStep > $this->totalSteps){
            $this->currentStep = $this->totalSteps;
        }
    }

    public function decreaseStep(){
        $this->resetErrorBag();
        $this->currentStep--;
        if($this->currentStep < 1){
            $this->currentStep = 1;
            //render();
        }
    }


    protected function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'ordini.name' => [
                'string',
                'nullable',
            ],
            'ordini.cliente_id' => [
                'integer',
                'exists:customers,id',
                'nullable',
            ],
            'prodotti' => [
                'array',
            ],
            'prodotti.*.id' => [
                'integer',
                'exists:products,id',
            ],
            'ordini.id_tipo' => [
                'integer',
                'min:-2147483648',
                'max:2147483647',
                'nullable',
            ],
        ];
    }

    protected function initListsForFields(): void
    {
        $this->listsForFields['cliente']  = Customer::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
        $this->listsForFields['prodotti'] = Product::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
    }
}
```

and my other blade select list

```
<pre>
 <div>
    <div wire:ignore class="w-full">
        @if(isset($attributes['multiple']))
            <div id="{{ $attributes['id'] }}-btn-container" class="mb-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm select-all-button">{{ trans('global.select_all') }}</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm deselect-all-button">{{ trans('global.deselect_all') }}</button>
            </div>
        @endif
        <select class="select2 form-control" data-placeholder="{{ __('Select your option') }}" {{ $attributes }}>
            @if(!isset($attributes['multiple']))
                <option></option>
            @endif
            @foreach($options as $key => $value)
                <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

@push('scripts')
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("livewire:load", () => {
    let el = $('#{{ $attributes['id'] }}')
    let buttonsId = '#{{ $attributes['id'] }}-btn-container'

    function initButtons() {
        $(buttonsId + ' .select-all-button').click(function (e) {
            el.val(_.map(el.find('option'), opt => $(opt).attr('value')))
            el.trigger('change')
        })

        $(buttonsId + ' .deselect-all-button').click(function (e) {
            el.val([])
            el.trigger('change')
        })
    }

    function initSelect () {
        initButtons()
        el.select2({
            placeholder: '{{ __('Select your option') }}',
            allowClear: !el.attr('required')
        })
    }

    initSelect()

    Livewire.hook('message.processed', (message, component) => {
        initSelect()
    });

    el.on('change', function (e) {
        let data = $(this).select2("val")
        if (data === "") {
            data = null
        }
@this.set('{{ $attributes['wire:model'] }}', data)
    });
});
    </script>
@endpush  
</pre>
```

i have 2 problem i want different variable from javascript in this 3 step and in final page i want make a summary of 3 different preset and save to my database like:

```
id_client: = 1 ; order_1d =1 sub_order = 1

id_client: = 1 ; order_1d =1 sub_order = 2

id_client: = 1 ; order_1d =1 sub_order = 3
```

I want save in my database the information corretct

[image]

thia ia my create order, with button next i make another page, that page is same . And i want 3 oh these. In the last page i want alle the information

Comment: Can you explain how a user is using your website and how the three values should be computed? We do not have a ready-made test and we only know what you describe in your question, so you will need to provide more information in general in order to get meaningful answers. So far it seems that you can store your three values in `localStorage`, update them when you need and POST the results to your server. But the question is just too vague at this point for me to provide a proper answer.

Comment: for each card I have to memorize the product and some of its characteristics. I can take up to 5 products. All this I have to do three times. A card contains the drugs that patients take, and are divided into those of the morning, those of the day and those of the evening. So the information for all three parties is always the same

Comment: Do you have some functionalities that compute these values?

Comment: they are not calculated values, but stored in the product sheet

Comment: Understood. Can you paste the relevant part of the **generated** HTML? I'm only interested in your product sheet. I know you have provided your template, but I'm interested in the actual HTML that's generated from it and I'm only interested in your form in HTML. If you provide that, then there will be a higher chance that I will be able to help you.

Comment: I have already posted all the html code related to the form

Comment: You have posted all the template. Instead of that I asked the actual HTML generated from it. You can find that by right-clicking in your browser, click on View Page Source, in the resulting HTML navigate to your form, copy the form and only the form (to make sure that the problem-space you present is minimal) and add it to your question. Thanks!

Comment: pleae anyone help me

Comment: I have seen you have shared the HTML in an answer. I cannot look into it right now, but later today I will have a look.

Comment: I have taken a look at your HTML. It seems to me that for `id_client` you would need to mine the value of `<select class="select2 form-control" data-placeholder="Select your option" class="form-control" id="cliente" name="cliente" wire:model="ordini.cliente_id">`, which you can achieve in Javascript via `let cliente = document.getElementById("cliente").value;` and then you can store that value.

Comment: Do I understand properly your goal about what needs to be gathered for `cliente`?

Comment: Because if this is correct, then I can write an answer for you, as long as you specify exactly what element holds the values you intend to provide for order and suborder.

Comment: i think i solve my problem, i save my sub-order in 3 different pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script src="/livewire/livewire.js?id=fe747446aa84856d8b66" data-turbo-eval="false" data-turbolinks-eval="false" ></script>
<script data-turbo-eval="false" data-turbolinks-eval="false" >
    if (window.livewire) {
        console.warn('Livewire: It looks like Livewire\'s @livewireScripts JavaScript assets have already been loaded. Make sure you aren\'t loading them twice.')
    }

    window.livewire = new Livewire();
    window.livewire.devTools(true);
    window.Livewire = window.livewire;
    window.livewire_app_url = '';
    window.livewire_token = 'LiGD9aaMhsaTAMbE2HLPKJxze6dHcqHyVEYphnce';

    /* Make sure Livewire loads first. */
    if (window.Alpine) {
        /* Defer showing the warning so it doesn't get buried under downstream errors. */
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.warn("Livewire: It looks like AlpineJS has already been loaded. Make sure Livewire\'s scripts are loaded before Alpine.\\n\\n Reference docs for more info: http://laravel-livewire.com/docs/alpine-js")
            })
        });
    }

    /* Make Alpine wait until Livewire is finished rendering to do its thing. */
    window.deferLoadingAlpine = function (callback) {
        window.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
            callback();
        });
    };

    let started = false;

    window.addEventListener('alpine:initializing', function () {
        if (! started) {
            window.livewire.start();

            started = true;
        }
    });

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        if (! started) {
            window.livewire.start();

            started = true;
        }
    });
</script>
                    <script>
        document.addEventListener("livewire:load", () => {
    let el = $('#cliente')
    let buttonsId = '#cliente-btn-container'

    function initButtons() {
        $(buttonsId + ' .select-all-button').click(function (e) {
            el.val(_.map(el.find('option'), opt => $(opt).attr('value')))
            el.trigger('change')
        })

        $(buttonsId + ' .deselect-all-button').click(function (e) {
            el.val([])
            el.trigger('change')
        })
    }

    function initSelect () {
        initButtons()
        el.select2({
            placeholder: 'Select your option',
            allowClear: !el.attr('required')
        })
    }

    initSelect()

    Livewire.hook('message.processed', (message, component) => {
        initSelect()
    });

    el.on('change', function (e) {
        let data = $(this).select2("val")
        if (data === "") {
            data = null
        }
window.livewire.find('FwZQBSk0vKOUXsLR3jIh').set('ordini.cliente_id', data)
    });
});
    </script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("livewire:load", () => {
    let el = $('#prodotti')
    let buttonsId = '#prodotti-btn-container'

    function initButtons() {
        $(buttonsId + ' .select-all-button').click(function (e) {
            el.val(_.map(el.find('option'), opt => $(opt).attr('value')))
            el.trigger('change')
        })

        $(buttonsId + ' .deselect-all-button').click(function (e) {
            el.val([])
            el.trigger('change')
        })
    }

    function initSelect () {
        initButtons()
        el.select2({
            placeholder: 'Select your option',
            allowClear: !el.attr('required')
        })
    }

    initSelect()

    Livewire.hook('message.processed', (message, component) => {
        initSelect()
    });

    el.on('change', function (e) {
        let data = $(this).select2("val")
        if (data === "") {
            data = null
        }
window.livewire.find('FwZQBSk0vKOUXsLR3jIh').set('prodotti', data)
    });
});
    </script>
        <script>
            function closeAlert(event){
        let element = event.target;
        while(element.nodeName !== "BUTTON"){
          element = element.parentNode;
        }
        element.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(element.parentNode);
      }
        </script>
</body>
```

```html
    <form>

        

        

            <div class="step-one">
                <div class="card">

                    <div class="card-header text-xl text-pink-400">Farmaci della mattina</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="cliente">Cliente</label>
                                    <div>
    <div wire:ignore class="w-full">
                <select class="select2 form-control" data-placeholder="Select your option" class="form-control" id="cliente" name="cliente" wire:model="ordini.cliente_id">
                            <option></option>
                                        <option value="1">Raffaele Filomena</option>
                            <option value="2">maria colella</option>
                    </select>
    </div>
</div>

                                    <div class="validation-message">
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="help-block">
                                         
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="prodotti">Prodotti</label>
                                    <div>
    <div wire:ignore class="w-full">
                    <div id="prodotti-btn-container" class="mb-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm select-all-button">Seleziona tutto</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm deselect-all-button">Deseleziona tutto</button>
            </div>
                <select class="select2 form-control" data-placeholder="Select your option" class="form-control" id="prodotti" name="prodotti" wire:model="prodotti" multiple="multiple">
                                        <option value="1">Acediur</option>
                            <option value="2">Bisolvon</option>
                            <option value="3">Cardioaspirina</option>
                    </select>
    </div>
</div>

                                    <div class="validation-message">
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="help-block">
                                         
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Description</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" cols="2" rows="2" wire:model="description"></textarea>
                            <span class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        

                

        
        
        
        <div class="action-buttons d-flex justify-content-between bg-white pt-2 pb-2">

                            <div></div>
            
            
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-success" wire:click="increaseStep()">Next</button>
            
            

        </div>

    </form>


</div>

<!-- Livewire Component wire-end:FwZQBSk0vKOUXsLR3jIh -->        </div>
    </div>
</div>

                <footer class="block py-4">
    <div class="container mx-auto px-4">
        <hr class="mb-4 border-b-1 border-blueGray-200">
        <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center md:justify-between justify-center">
            <div class="w-full md:w-4/12 px-4">
                <div class="text-sm text-blueGray-500 font-semibold py-1 text-center md:text-left">
                    <div class="hidden">
                        Copyright © <span id="get-current-year">2023</span>
                    </div>
                    Theme <a href="https://www.creative-tim.com/product/notus-js" class="text-blueGray-500 hover:text-blueGray-700 text-sm font-semibold py-1" target="_blank">NotusJS</a> by
                    <a href="https://www.creative-tim.com" class="text-blueGray-500 hover:text-blueGray-700 text-sm font-semibold py-1" target="_blank">
                        Creative Tim
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w-full md:w-8/12 px-4">
                <ul class="flex flex-wrap list-none md:justify-end justify-center hidden">
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.creative-tim.com?ref=njs-settings" class="text-blueGray-600 hover:text-blueGray-800 text-sm font-semibold block py-1 px-3">
                            Creative Tim
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.creative-tim.com/presentation?ref=njs-settings" class="text-blueGray-600 hover:text-blueGray-800 text-sm font-semibold block py-1 px-3">
                            About Us
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://blog.creative-tim.com?ref=njs-settings" class="text-blueGray-600 hover:text-blueGray-800 text-sm font-semibold block py-1 px-3">
                            Blog
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://github.com/creativetimofficial/notus-js/blob/main/LICENSE.md?ref=njs-settings" class="text-blueGray-600 hover:text-blueGray-800 text-sm font-semibold block py-1 px-3">
                            MIT License
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <form id="logoutform" action="http://farma.raf/logout" method="POST" style="display: none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="LiGD9aaMhsaTAMbE2HLPKJxze6dHcqHyVEYphnce">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://farma.raf/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
    <!-- Livewire Scripts -->
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at a controller method:

```
public function submit() {
    $this->validate();
    $this->ordini->save();
    $this->ordini->prodotti()->sync($this->prodotti);
    $this->ordini->prodotti1()->sync($this->prodotti1);
    $this->ordini->prodotti2()->sync($this->prodotti2);
    return redirect()->route('admin.ordinis.index');
}
```

And the relationship definitions of the model classes:

```
public function prodotti() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}

public function prodotti1() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'ordini_product1');
}

public function prodotti2() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'ordini_product2');
}
```

Now, when I save my sub-order in 3 different pivot tables it works fine.
However, I have 3 different steps to insert the order, but I need to reload my javascript for the list box. How can I make this?

Comment: Wait, is this answer not just additional information about the question? If so, it should be moved to be part of the question instead.